in kaggle data sets, how do you read from zipped files where unzipping them is not possible due to memory constraints?
In kaggle I am working with the data set: /kaggle/input/diabetic-retinopathy-detection, however I am having trouble trying to read in the train data. They are five zip files, how do I read say a few images from them at a time?
I can thus far download all the zip files, and unzip the data (38GB) and then read the images as input for my deep learning models. However, I need to do this kaggle: either read the data directly from the dataset provided, or unzip it to where there is sufficient storage.
Does anyone know how to read in dataset data from large files?
